# From Where are Publishing Priorities are fetched?

Tags: publishing, gui-extensions

While I was going through the *Publish.js*, I found a predefined method `Tridion.ContentManager.Model.getListPublishPriorities()`.

From where does this method fetches the Priority List?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It gets it from the Core Service (`GetEnumValues` method) which in turn has the actual values as an `enum` and string resources for the labels that will be displayed in the user's chosen language.

In other words, the list of values is fixed and you cannot change them.

Answer (score 6):

As I see this is internal functionality of the product, so maybe some details how it works can provide someone from SDL. 
The question here is what are you trying to achieve, since I am not sure that managing list of publish priorities can be done (adding "ultra super hype priority"). Instead of changing this list, I would suggest using security to deny/allow some users to publish on high/normal.

Comment: Hi Thanks For reply, would you please let me know how we can restrict some users to use High Priority

Answer (score 4):

Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.xml file set  the publishing targets. please check below code with file path. this sdlweb product code, we can`t modify directly.

```
    \tridion\bin\client\CoreService\Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.xml

 <member name="F:Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.PublishPriority.Low">
                <summary>
                Low priority.
                </summary>
            </member>
            <member name="F:Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.PublishPriority.Normal">
                <summary>
                Normal priority.
                </summary>
            </member>
            <member name="F:Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.PublishPriority.High">
                <summary>
                High priority.
                </summary>
            </member>

tridion\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Tabs\TargetTypes.js

Tridion.Cme.TargetTypesTab.PRIORITY_DROPDOWN_HEAD_PATH = $config.expandEditorPath("Xml/ListDefinitions/TargetTypePriorityDropdown-head.xml", $const.CMEEditorName);
```